# Trying to understand this summation property $\sum_{i} \frac{a_i(b_i + rc_i)}{1+rd_i}$

Tags: summation, solution-verification

I'm having a big problem trying to understand how to go from this

$$\sum_{i} \frac{a_i(b_i + rc_i)}{1+rd_i} $$

to this

$$\sum_{k} a_k(b_k+rc_k)\prod_{j\neq k}(1+rd_j) $$

The idea is that the summation in the first equation needs to be rewritten in the summation/product form in the second equation in order to later expand the product term.

Any tips, clues or comments are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing the denominator in the second expression. Assuming this, the idea is simply to make the denominators of all the terms in the first summation equal, by multiplying $$\prod _{j\neq i} (1+rd_j)$$ to both the numerator and denominator of the $i$th term of the summation, for all $i$. The common denominator to all the terms would then be $$\prod _{j} (1+rd_j)$$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kadoodle. I took the equations directly from a paper so I don't think I'm missing the denominator.